# Can I set display name for column while selecting from Database?

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

Is it possible to set the display name for column while selecting from database? This could save me from writing hundrends of lines of code.  Can I do something like..

```
var alerts = entities.Alerts.Select(x => new
                    {
                        "Destination IP" = x.destination_ip
                    });
```

This `LINQ` later gets converted into `DataSet` to use with `ObjectDataSource`. `DataGrid` uses `ObjectDataSource`. There are DataGrids all over the project and I have to write code to set `HeaderText` for each column in UI.

Currently I am using `BoundField` just to set the `HeaderText`.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="destination_ip" HeaderText="Destination IP" />
```

I don't want to do this extra code. Any other approach would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: How you are loading data from database?

Comment: @Nazmul: I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: Ok you just need to get an extra field try this "Destination IP" = x.destination_ip,"DisplayName" = x.DisplayName

Comment: Select another column just like you have selected Destination.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: This doesn't make any sense. I want to set display name for destination_ip column. DisplayName is not another property.

Comment: Is there any column named "Dispaly name" in your table? Are you trying to add this property in your select query ?

Comment: The datatable names can be found in dt.Columns[index].ColumnName.  So if you have the index to the column you can get the name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958).? You can do it if you are using code first.

You can achieve it by following way:

```
public class MyModel
{        
    [Display(Name = "labelForName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work, however, for this I need to create class for each grid and set properties in LINQ. I'm not using code first.

Comment: So what are using then?

Comment: I am using database first. For displaying using `BoundField` with `AutoGenerateColumn='False'`